# Conditional batch rename (Windows XP)

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, windows-xp, batch-rename

I have several hundred files whose names have a sequential index at the end:

```
recipes0001.jpg
recipes0002.jpg
...
recipes0283.jpg
```

I need to rename them so that the index starts at 976 (not 1) and the leading 0 becomes a '1' when the index reaches 1000

```
recipes0976.jpg
recipes0977.jpg
...
recipes1000.jpg
recipes1001.jpg
....
```

I have written this batch code (a modified answer from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/347931/how-do-i-rename-a-bunch-of-files-in-the-command-prompt)):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set i=975
for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
    set /a i+=1
    if i lss 1000 ren "%%a" "recipes0!i!.new"
    if i geq 1000 ren "%%a" "recipes!i!.new"
)
ren *.new *.jpg
```

It seems that the code always runs the part without the leading 0 since I keep getting `recipes976.jpg`, `recipes1001.jpg` etc. What am I doing wrong?

As a follow-up question, can the two `if`'s be combined into one `if`...`else`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare the value of the variable `i`, you need to expand it when passing it to the `if` command.

```
if !i! lss 1000 (
  ren "%%a" "recipes0!i!.new"
)^
else (
  ren "%%a" "recipes!i!.new"
)
```

Comment: Why using such odd syntax? Why not writing `) else (` into a single line as suggested in the help (see `if /?`)?

Comment: The only reason that I write it like that is personal preference. The idea comes from writing stream redirection before or after a command. I prefer to write stream redirection after the command, so I don't have to read through the line of text to see which command is being used. I might have a bit of an odd preference but it's just a preference.

Comment: I don't get how this `else` syntax is linked to redirection, but it's your preference anyway, so it's fine for me... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I would do this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set i=10975
for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
    set /a i+=1
    ren "%%a" "recipes!i:~1!.new"
)
ren *.new *.jpg
```

Comment: Another elegant solution, thanks. For those who don't know, the `:~1` part builds a substring of the original `10975` string by selecting all elements whose position is 1 or larger (the fist element has position 0, the second 1, etc.).